# VBS files worked on my old PC, but now won't run (and also freeze when run via cscript in command prompt)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I've tried this with multiple VBS files, including new ones and a folder of some old ones (which were simple mp3 bell-sound timers) from my old computer. I'm on 64-bit Windows 10. I don't know if my previous PC was 32-bit or 64-bit. When I try to run them in the command line or batch files via cscript, it just displays this and freezes with the usual ticking underscore _ floating on the line beneath:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
_
```

As though it's looping some process offscreen. When I x out, it takes a noticeable second to close properly. It feels like Windows Script Host (cscript.exe, right?) needs repairing, so I'm also trying to figure out how to do that. Opening cscript (Windows Script Host?) on its own in cmd gives me a working menu of options to use, so that part works at least.

However, the scripts do work when I run them inside the VbsEdit software, so the code is fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Since an example of the code is needed, here is my 5-minute bell timer script which works just fine in VbsEdit:

```
Dim oPlayer
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

' Play audio
oPlayer.URL = "C:\Users\FTSQS\Bell.mp3"
oPlayer.controls.play 
While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

' Release the audio file
oPlayer.close
```

But this is just an example. None of the VBS files seem to work on their own.

Comment: Care to share the actual code you are using and how exactly you are executing them? Please take the [tour] like you were asked to when you joined the site. Please read [ask] a good question. Always provide a [mcve] of the code you are using and any associated input.

Comment: Didn't think a code sample was necessary in this instance, but I updated it with an example nonetheless.

Comment: My question asked for two things. You only provided one.

Comment: Try running one of the problem scripts in 32 bit mode like this: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe yourscript.vbs`

Comment: I execute them with cscript (simply: cscript.exe 5MinuteTimer.vbs) in batch files & cmd which causes the freeze result, but I have also tried simply clicking on the VBS, which seemingly causes nothing to occur.

Comment: In that case, try `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe yourscript.vbs`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by specifying C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe - thanks to LesFerch for the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).